# Correct design pattern of multiple inheritance of abstract class

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, abc

I have a complex class structure such has this one below:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
# Abstract Foo Space
class Foo(ABC):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @abstractmethod
    def foo_something(self):
        pass

class ChildFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, value, extended_foo):
        Foo.__init__(self, value=value)
        self.extended_foo = extended_foo

    def foo_something(self):
        print(self.extended_foo)



# Abstract Bar Space, extend Foo
class Bar(Foo, ABC):
    def __init__(self, value, extended_bar):
        Foo.__init__(self, value=value)
        self.extended_bar = extended_bar

    @abstractmethod
    def bar_something(self):
        pass


class ChildBarFoo(Bar, ChildFoo):
    def __init__(self, value, extended_foo, extended_bar):
        Bar.__init__(self, value=value, extended_bar=extended_bar)
        ChildFoo.__init__(self, value=value, extended_foo=extended_foo)

    def bar_something(self):
        print(self.extended_bar)

my_object = ChildBarFoo(value=100, extended_foo='foo', extended_bar='bar')
my_object.bar_something()
my_object.foo_something()
```

When I instantiate `ChildBarFoo`, `Foo` will be initiated twice, once from `ChildFoo` and once from `Bar` which makes me wonder if the pattern I am using is correct.

Comment: Complex inheritance hierarchies often are a sign of bad design and can almost always be replaced with other techniques like composition. Without more context, however, it is difficult to give you a concrete solution for your problem. Maybe it helps to reconsider the relationships between the classes (is-a vs has-a) to get you on the right track.

Comment: @DocDriven yes I agree, Trying to simplify it as much as I can so it's somewhat 'clear'. probably no good answer to this question...